# My compilation produces a result that is not the same as what the author got

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I tried the following code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-6.5,-3.5)(6.5,3)
\psset{viewpoint=30 0 15 rtp2xyz,Decran=30,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSolid[object=tore,r1=5,r0=1,ngrid=36 36,tablez=0 0.05 1 {} for,
          zcolor= 1 .5 .5 .5 .5 1,action=none,name=Torus]
\pstVerb{/R1 5 def /R0 1.2 def /k 20 def /RL 0.15 def /kRL 40 def}%
\defFunction[algebraic]{helix}(t)
     {(R1+R0*cos(k*t))*sin(t)+RL*sin(kRL*k*t)}
     {(R1+R0*cos(k*t))*cos(t)+RL*cos(kRL*k*t)}
     {R0*sin(k*t)+RL*sin(kRL*k*t)}
\psSolid[object=courbe,
        resolution=7800,
        fillcolor=black,incolor=black,
        r=0,
        range=0 6.2831853,
        function=helix,action=none,name=Helix]%
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=Torus Helix,grid]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

hopefully to get the same result as what Herbert's did in [the site he maintains](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D).

The expected result should be as follows,

[image]

Unfortunately I got the following result,

[image]

Note that I have tried the same code many times since the first day the code was publicly available. I also have reinstalled my operating system and the TeX Live distribution. I have just updated the installed TeX Live as well.

Comment: I tried with TeX Live 2012, 2011 and 2010, with the same result.

Comment: With miktex 2.9 I get also the "broken" picture.

Comment: I confirm that with miktex 2.9 the picture is broken `:-(`

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: the update of the files is on CTAN and should be (hopefully) available tomorrow with TL and later with MiKTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my filelist for a correct image. All files are available from http://texnik.dante.de

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2012/08/24 v0.53 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2012/09/23 v2.33 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2012/09/23 v2.33 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks.pro    2012/10/16 v. 1.15, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-algparser.pro    2011/10/31 v. 0.04, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-tools.pro    2012/01/01 v. 0.02, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-dots.pro    2006/12/19 v. 2.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
pst-solides3d.sty    2009/07/25 package wrapper for pst-solides3d
pst-solides3d.tex    2011/07/13 v4.24 `PST-solides3D'
pst-solides3d.pro    2010/04/27 v. 4.20, PostScript prologue file
```

Comment: The `exa042.tex` file doesn't produce that file list; for instance, it uses the `minimal` class. The `pst-solides3d.tex` file in TeX Live is still 4.23

Comment: The file list depends to the above code and you should know that it makes no difference using the minimal or standalone class when you do not have any text in your example.